# Need help to make a RegExp filter to replace redundant Parentheses

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, intellij-idea, actionscript

For the past few days (weeks, months, years maybe if you count my on-again off-again search and attempts) I've been trying to make or find a RegEx filter to help me remove all redundant parentheses found in my code.

A worst case scenario of what the regex filter will have to deal with is attached. As is a best case scenario

> return ((((((((((((((((((((((((((getHumanReadableLine("avHardwareDisable") + getHumanReadableLine("hasAccessibility")) + getHumanReadableLine("hasAudio")) + getHumanReadableLine("hasAudioEncoder")) + getHumanReadableLine("hasEmbeddedVideo")) + getHumanReadableLine("hasIME")) + getHumanReadableLine("hasMP3")) + getHumanReadableLine("hasPrinting")) + getHumanReadableLine("hasScreenBroadcast")) + getHumanReadableLine("hasScreenPlayback")) + getHumanReadableLine("hasStreamingAudio")) + getHumanReadableLine("hasStreamingVideo")) + getHumanReadableLine("hasTLS")) + getHumanReadableLine("hasVideoEncoder")) + getHumanReadableLine("isDebugger")) + getHumanReadableLine("language")) + getHumanReadableLine("localFileReadDisable")) + getHumanReadableLine("manufacturer")) + getHumanReadableLine("os")) + getHumanReadableLine("pixelAspectRatio")) + getHumanReadableLine("playerType")) + getHumanReadableLine("screenColor")) + getHumanReadableLine("screenDPI")) + getHumanReadableLine("screenResolutionX")) + getHumanReadableLine("screenResolutionY")) + getHumanReadableLine("version")));
>
> > return ((((name + ": ") + Capabilities[name]) + "\n"));

As you can see there's... a few... redundant parentheses in my code. Been working actively with these for a very long time but have always tried to clean up what I come across and been trying to find a faster way to do it.

So one example of how the "clean" code would look, I'm hoping at least!

> return (name + ": "  + Capabilities[name]  + "\n");
>
> > return name + ": "  + Capabilities[name]  + "\n";

Either one is acceptable to be completely honest as long as the code itself doesn't mock up and change how it works.

I greatly appreciate any answers anyone can give me. Please don't Mock what I do or am trying to achieve. I haven't worked much with regex or similar things before...

And just to humour you... Here's my "RegExp" for my "clean" example

> (return) ({1,}((.[^)]{1,}))(.{1,}))(.{1,})){1,}
>
> > $1 $2 $3 $4 // output

oh... Forgot to mention

> (!(testCrossZ()))

Might appear at times as well but those aren't as big of an issue to clean up manually if needed.

P.S... There is a "LOT" of occurances of the redundant parentheses... Like... Maybe thousands... Most likely thousands.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it applies for actionscript, but for Java you can do: `Main Menu | Analyze | Run Inspection by Name | type "parentheses" | select "Unnecessary parentheses" | run in the whole project and fix all problems`

Result:

```
return getHumanReadableLine("avHardwareDisable") + getHumanReadableLine("hasAccessibility")
    + getHumanReadableLine("hasAudio") + getHumanReadableLine("hasAudioEncoder")
    + getHumanReadableLine("hasEmbeddedVideo") + getHumanReadableLine("hasIME")
    + getHumanReadableLine("hasMP3") + getHumanReadableLine("hasPrinting")
    + getHumanReadableLine("hasScreenBroadcast") + getHumanReadableLine("hasScreenPlayback")
    + getHumanReadableLine("hasStreamingAudio") + getHumanReadableLine("hasStreamingVideo")
    + getHumanReadableLine("hasTLS") + getHumanReadableLine("hasVideoEncoder")
    + getHumanReadableLine("isDebugger") + getHumanReadableLine("language")
    + getHumanReadableLine("localFileReadDisable") + getHumanReadableLine("manufacturer")
    + getHumanReadableLine("os") + getHumanReadableLine("pixelAspectRatio")
    + getHumanReadableLine("playerType") + getHumanReadableLine("screenColor")
    + getHumanReadableLine("screenDPI") + getHumanReadableLine("screenResolutionX")
    + getHumanReadableLine("screenResolutionY") + getHumanReadableLine("version");
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the IntelliJ shows unnecessary parenthesis when looking at it in Actionscript code, if you have not disabled the inspection. And I think there is a way to invoke a fix for the problem from the occurance either for the whole file, if not for the project. I will check as soon as possible and bring more information. (Which version of IntelliJ are you using?)

Answer (score 0):

I honestly haven't understood the exact form of the output format that you wanted but as per starters at least clearing off the unnecessary parenthesis can be done with pure JavaScript as follows.

```js
var  text = 'return ((((((((((((((((((((((((((getHumanReadableLine("avHardwareDisable") + getHumanReadableLine("hasAccessibility")) + getHumanReadableLine("hasAudio")) + getHumanReadableLine("hasAudioEncoder")) + getHumanReadableLine("hasEmbeddedVideo")) + getHumanReadableLine("hasIME")) + getHumanReadableLine("hasMP3")) + getHumanReadableLine("hasPrinting")) + getHumanReadableLine("hasScreenBroadcast")) + getHumanReadableLine("hasScreenPlayback")) + getHumanReadableLine("hasStreamingAudio")) + getHumanReadableLine("hasStreamingVideo")) + getHumanReadableLine("hasTLS")) + getHumanReadableLine("hasVideoEncoder")) + getHumanReadableLine("isDebugger")) + getHumanReadableLine("language")) + getHumanReadableLine("localFileReadDisable")) + getHumanReadableLine("manufacturer")) + getHumanReadableLine("os")) + getHumanReadableLine("pixelAspectRatio")) + getHumanReadableLine("playerType")) + getHumanReadableLine("screenColor")) + getHumanReadableLine("screenDPI")) + getHumanReadableLine("screenResolutionX")) + getHumanReadableLine("screenResolutionY")) + getHumanReadableLine("version")));',
        r = /\(((getHumanReadableLine\("\w+"\)[\s\+]*)+)\)/g,
     temp = "";
while (text != temp) {
  temp = text;
  text = text.replace(r,"$1");
}
document.write('<pre>' + text + '</pre>');
```

From this point on, it shouldn't be a big deal to convert the reduced text into the desired output format.

Comment: I just love https://regex101.com/r/wC5eK7/1 for working on, understanding and improving regular expressions. Actionscript RegExpr are somewhat similar to what JavaScript offers.